# Difference between Unity's [Command] and [Server]

Tags: unity, unity-networking

[Command] and [Server] functions both run on the server and can also be called by a local player but what is the difference between them?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure myself, but I do know that [COMMAND] attribute is only for use on PLAYER controlled objects. That might be something to do with it (I'm also learning Unity Network gaming ~gradually~ at the moment :]

Comment: It may not be advisable to learn UNet too deeply, it is being deprecated and replaced in the next six to 12 months.

Comment: @SuperMegaBroBro Yeah it may help to understand.

Comment: @Draco18s I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They actually do quite different things according to the documentation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CommandAttribute.html

> [Command] functions are invoked on the player GameObject associated with a connection

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.ServerAttribute.html

> A [Server] method returns immediately if NetworkServer.active is not true, and generates a warning on the console

But be sure to be mindful of the comment by Draco18s:

> It may not be advisable to learn UNet too deeply, it is being deprecated and replaced in the next six to 12 months

Comment: I'll keep in mind what @Darco118s said. But I wanted to know that [Command] is called by the player object, **but who calls [Server] function.**

Comment: I don't think it matters who or what calls a [Server] attribute. The way I understand it is that you wanna use the [Server] attribute for any function that absolutely has to be connected to the server.

Comment: @HapppyGuyDk Ok